# Time varying coefficient in Cox model

Tags: r, regression, survival, regression-coefficients, cox-model

I have a model for survival after an injury that is borderline passing the Schoenfeld test for the proportional hazards assumption (`cox.zph()` in R).

However, suspecting that there would be an increased mortality within the first month I fitted an Aalen additive regression model also hinting at a varying coefficient since the cumulative coefficient drops steeply within the first 4 days, then gradually continues to decline before it stabilizes at a nearly constant level after a year for my variable of interest.

Now - how can I accommodate such a model in R?

- Introduce an interaction term [for my variable of interest] varying with time?
- Create different variables for time 0-4, 4-365 and 365 and then also expand the dataset with three rows per patient?

Comment: Have you plotted the hazard ratio changes over time (plot the results of the `cox.zph()` created object)? This gives you some idea about the possible implications for the changes in hazard ratio over time for your variable of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Just answered my [own question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/time-dependent-coefficients-in-r-how-to-do-it/204294#204294) with the same problem. Basically you need to do a time-split as you describe and then add an interaction term for the time. As you suggested it sounds like a good idea to perhaps split the time more fine grained in the beginning and then increase the intervals. Using my [Greg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Greg/) package you can set the by-time to either a single interval or to a vector, e.g. if we create a dataset with four subjects:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  time = c(4, 3.5, 1, 5),
  event = c("censored", "dead", "alive", "dead"),
  age = c(62.2, 55.3, 73.7, 46.3),
  date = as.Date(
    c("2003-01-01", 
      "2010-04-01", 
      "2013-09-20",
      "2002-02-23")))
```

Looking like this:

```
| id| time|event    |  age|date       |
|--:|----:|:--------|----:|:----------|
|  1|  4.0|censored | 62.2|2003-01-01 |
|  2|  3.5|dead     | 55.3|2010-04-01 |
|  3|  1.0|alive    | 73.7|2013-09-20 |
|  4|  5.0|dead     | 46.3|2002-02-23 |
```

We split each subject into several through:

```
library(Greg)
library(dplyr)
split_data <- 
  test_data %>% 
  select(id, event, time, age, date) %>% 
  timeSplitter(by = c(.1, .5, 2), # The time that we want to split by
               event_var = "event",
               time_var = "time",
               event_start_status = "alive",
               time_related_vars = c("age", "date"))

knitr::kable(split_data)
```

Gives:

```
| id|event    |  age|     date| Start_time| Stop_time|
|--:|:--------|----:|--------:|----------:|---------:|
|  1|alive    | 62.2| 2002.999|        0.0|       0.1|
|  1|alive    | 62.3| 2003.099|        0.1|       0.5|
|  1|alive    | 62.7| 2003.499|        0.5|       2.0|
|  1|censored | 64.2| 2004.999|        2.0|       4.0|
|  2|alive    | 55.3| 2010.246|        0.0|       0.1|
|  2|alive    | 55.4| 2010.346|        0.1|       0.5|
|  2|alive    | 55.8| 2010.746|        0.5|       2.0|
|  2|dead     | 57.3| 2012.246|        2.0|       3.5|
|  3|alive    | 73.7| 2013.718|        0.0|       0.1|
|  3|alive    | 73.8| 2013.818|        0.1|       0.5|
|  3|alive    | 74.2| 2014.218|        0.5|       1.0|
|  4|alive    | 46.3| 2002.145|        0.0|       0.1|
|  4|alive    | 46.4| 2002.245|        0.1|       0.5|
|  4|alive    | 46.8| 2002.645|        0.5|       2.0|
|  4|dead     | 48.3| 2004.145|        2.0|       5.0|
```

As described in my previous answer you now just need to model using `Surv(Start_time, End_time, event)` together with an additional `:` interaction term for your variable (note that you should also have the variable without the interaction in the model).